# Observable being sampled is flooding with events

Tags: android, rx-java, debouncing

I'm trying to sample the output of a slider in Android.

The set up is:
A PublishSubject mSubjTrim. In the OnTouchEvent of the slider, I call mSubjTrim.onNext(progress)

I create an observable from mSubjTrim

```
public final Observable<Integer> mObsTrim = mSubTrim.sample(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

(it's set to seconds because it's easier to see logging of output in increments of seconds. In actual use this would be about 50ms sample)

I subscribe to mObsTrim like so:

```
RxBus.Instance().mObsTrim.subscribe(trim -> {
            Logy.CallPrint(LOGY_ENABLE, CLASSNAME, "Trim Change");
            DispatchTrimChange(trim);
        });
```

The output upon tweaking the slider results in the following output however

```
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456738766 // @timeOfEvent via System.currentTimeMillis()
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745764
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745765
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745765
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745766
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745766
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745766
ParameterSender*::Trim Change @1473456745767
```

This is hardly working as sample is described to work.

I also try

```
public final Observable<Integer> mObsTrim = mSubTrim.sample(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).debounce(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And the output is no different!

Why can't I just get a SINGLE update on trim every second?

**Edit**

So I added a logging message to the listener so I know when the last input was made at

```
MyActivity::SetTrim @1473458620018 // This is a single input event with nothing before it
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620287
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620288
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620288
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620289
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620289
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620289
ParameterSender*::Trim Change = -25.2 @1473458620290
```

Comment: Logy.CallPrint is just a small function that automates formatting and printing a debug message for me and appends the time of the message.

Comment: Could be that mObsTrim of the bus is not the sampled stream because you assigned the wrong Observable.

Comment: How could that be? It responds to the observable created from mSubTrim.asObservable(), just, it gets 7 events for every 1 onNext() call

Comment: Could you post a standalone, reproducible example?